# Audio Streaming on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming, mp3

I need to create an audio streamer for Android. I want it to play MP3(and other formats too if possible). I also want to be able to progressive download the audio. Does anyone knows a good way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an extremely broad question.  Can you start this project and break your question up into multiple pieces?  See the FAQ here:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq  You will get a much better response if you ask specific questions.

Comment: I just need to create an audio streamer with support to progressive download. That's all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should start by checking this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Apparently this is already done for video, since you can specify a URL as the source for your stream.

You also will have to check some references about audio streaming and the size of the buffering you should use, as well as its dependency with the rate at which you're getting data from the stream in question.